# What is the oscillation frequency of a buoyant cylinder?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, oscillators, buoyancy

Suppose a cylinder sits upright in "dry water" (zero viscosity). The cylinder has half the density of the water, and we'll ignore the dynamics of the atmosphere.

If I push the cylinder down some past its equilibrium, the buoyant force pushes back up. If I slowly increase the force I'm using to push down on the cylinder, I find a Hooke's law relationship. (This is why I mentioned a cylinder instead of a sphere, but answering for a sphere would be fine.)

However, if I set the cylinder oscillating, I don't think I can use just this restoring force and the cylinder's mass to find an oscillation frequency. I need to account for some sort of "effective mass" of the water. i.e. the oscillating cylinder puts kinetic energy into the water.

How would you estimate the appropriate mass of water to use? And how much power would the water carry away from the cylinder (e.g. by surface gravity waves) if it were started oscillating and set free? Let's also ignore surface tension for simplicity.

Comment: Hm ... in the usual form of the question for exercises the oscillations end up having a period that is many, many times $t_\text{sound} = (\text{size of the system})/(\text{speed of sound})$, which represents the minimum relaxation time of the system (and in all likely hood is smaller than the real relaxation time by a smallish factor). So treating the problem with static results makes a fairly minor error because the deviation from static behavior can be expected to be pretty small. But this does represent a very nice *"what have we missed and how do we improve the model"* exercise.

Comment: Isn't there a bulk flow of water to account for? When the cylinder moves down, it pushes some water out of the way.

Comment: If the system moves too fast the water would have to move largely up and down, but if the motion is 'slow' the flow may have a significant horizontal (away from and toward the center) than vertical component, so that there is less net momentum in the water that would be naively assumed. I do think the part of the question about the energy flow is really interesting, but I don't have time to work on it right now.

Comment: Relevant: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/surface-waves-generated-by-an-oscillating-circular-cylinder-on-water-of-finite-depth-theory-and-experiment/0105EF0389EE6E814EB3FC144ABA1097

Comment: Wait, you say it's dry water. So basically, the water molecules don't mechanically react with the system. There would be no transfer of energy, unless there is some viscosity.

Comment: How are the water molecules suppose to get out of the cylinder's way without picking up any kinetic energy?

Comment: The case for a fully submerged sphere can be analyzed exactly - in that case, the effective mass increase equals half the mass of the displaced liquid. With a cylinder that's partly submerged you have a few complications - you mentioned surface waves (which will probably make the restoring force appear _less_ ), and the differential equation of the flow around the object no longer appears so simple as with the sphere.

Comment: Eventually the cylinder will radiate all of its energy away (assuming it doesn't locally generate vorticity) so you could use a point source model of a cauchy-poisson process to work backwards from a wave field to the energy/momentum required to generate it.

Comment: @MarkEichenlaub The cylinder transfers kinetic energy to the water, yes, but as far as my understanding goes the water "returns" that energy to the cylinder in the work of the buoyant force, also the buoyant force is made by the water in reaction to the space displaced by the cylinder.

Comment: @Deltab I believe common usage of the term "buoyant force" would be for the forces that exist in a static situation; movement of the water would not be included.

Comment: @MarkEichenlaub it is not the buyoant force that pushes the cyclinder up? In a side note: I am not a native speaker of English, so pardon me for my weird phrases or word uses.

Comment: @Deltab Yes, the buoyant force pushes upward. It is the upward force you would feel if holding the cylinder stationary below its natural floating point, with all the water still.

Comment: It's a bit old, but here's a reference http://www.iaea.org/inis/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/09/411/9411273.pdf that addresses the question  of "effective mass and damping" for submerged structures.  It's in the context of determining the response of civil engineering (i.e. nuclear power plant) components to the excitation of an earthquake, so it's a bit more detailed than the question's scenario.  But it shows the various possibilities to consider.

Answer (score 1):

I must be missing something but isn't this just directly from a variation of [Hooke's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law)?  The [buoyancy force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buoyancy) is proportional to the density of the displaced fluid and the volume displaced, i.e., $\mathbf{F} = \rho \ V \ g$, where $\rho$ is the mass density of the water, $V$ is the volume of water displaced, and $g$ is the acceleration of gravity here.  If we ignore [viscosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity) and [surface tension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension) (which is probably okay for very massive cylinders), then we can assume a constant area and a linear dependence on the depth of the oscillating cylinder displaced from equilibrium.  We should also assume the cylinder is not tremendously long to avoid issues with varying gravity and pressures.

Then, in the limit of small oscillations the expression would just be:
$$
\mathbf{F} = \rho \ g \ A_{cyl} \ \Delta x \tag{0}
$$
where $A_{cyl}$ is the cross-sectional area of the cylinder and $\Delta x$ is the displacement from equilibrium.  That implies that we can say our "spring constant" is given by:
$$
k = \rho \ g \ A_{cyl} \tag{1}
$$

> However, if I set the cylinder oscillating, I don't think I can use just this restoring force and the cylinder's mass to find an oscillation frequency. I need to account for some sort of "effective mass" of the water. i.e. the oscillating cylinder puts kinetic energy into the water.

No, this is accounted for in the displaced fluid weight (i.e., the $\rho \ V$ terms).

> How would you estimate the appropriate mass of water to use?

Again, this is accounted for in the displaced fluid weight (i.e., the $\rho \ V$ terms).

> And how much power would the water carry away from the cylinder (e.g. by surface gravity waves) if it were started oscillating and set free?

This could be approximated by a damping term where the oscillating cylinder undergoes damped harmonic oscillation.  Since the oscillation is just a variation of Hooke's law, you can further modify it by adding a damping term in the typical fashion for a [damped harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator), e.g., add a term like $\nu \ \dot{\mathbf{x}}$ where $\nu$ is a damping rate and $\dot{\mathbf{x}}$ is the time-variation of the position (i.e., speed/velocity).

You can estimate the total initial energy as the typical potential energy of a harmonic oscillator with $U = k \ x^{2}/2$ and then determine $\nu$ by measuring the [e-folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-folding) time for the amplitude of the cylinder oscillations to decrease by a quantified amount.

## **Update**

There is a subtlety that I missed in my original answer in that the frequency is not constant.  The frequency of a constant-mass harmonic oscillator is given by $\omega = \sqrt{k/m}$.  Here, however, the $m$ is not constant and so the displacement-dependent frequency will be:
$$
\omega\left( \Delta x \right) = \sqrt{ \frac{k}{\rho \ A_{cyl} \ \Delta x} } = \sqrt{ \frac{g}{\Delta x} } \tag{2}
$$

The damping rate, $\nu$, will also depend upon the displacement of the cylinder from equilibrium as the amplitude of the driven waves depend upon the volume of fluid displaced.  Typically one shows that the frequency goes as $\omega^{2} = \omega_{o}^{2} - \nu^{2}/4$, where $\omega_{o} = \sqrt{k/m}$ is the standard harmonic oscillator resonance frequency and $\nu$ is a damping rate.

A simplifying assumption is to start with an initial $\Delta x$ that is small compared with the total cylinder length, $L$, and this allows us to argue that $\nu$ ~ constant (since the fluid displaced will change slowly and by a small amount).  Without any damping, the cylinder would oscillate at $\sqrt{ \tfrac{g}{\Delta x} }$ indefinitely but the damping here will alter the maximum $\Delta x$ of each subsequent oscillation.  So the amplitude and frequency of oscillations will change in time, i.e., the amplitude will decrease and the frequency should increase.

Comment: Could you please give an equation for the oscillation frequency you are proposing?

Comment: Ah I see now what was really the issue since the typical frequency depends upon k/m...  That would imply that $\omega = \sqrt{k/\Delta x}$, which is time-varying and greatly complicates things (from a math point of view).  I think I know the answer though as I recall working this out in grad school at some point...

Comment: Why don't we have to add [virtual mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Added_mass)?

Answer (score -2):

Let $\rho_{fl}$ and $\rho$ denote densities of the fluid and cylinder; $g$ the gravity field; $H$ the height of the cylinder and $A$ the area of the cylinder.

The cylinder is at a height $h$ above it's equilibrium position. There is a net downward force, equal to the downturn buoyancy force in magnitude. 
$$|F|=\rho_{fl}Ahg$$
Newton predicts
$$\rho AH\frac{d^2h}{dt^2}=-\rho_{fl}Agh$$

Which gives

$$T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{\rho H}{\rho_{fl}g}}$$

Comment: What you;ve done here is solve the usual homework exercise version of the problem, but Mark writes *"However, if I set the cylinder oscillating, I don't think I can use just this restoring force and the cylinder's mass to find an oscillation frequency. I need to account for some sort of "effective mass" of the water. i.e. the oscillating cylinder puts kinetic energy into the water. "* making it explicit that he wants you to look at the things neglected in the naive solution.

Comment: @dmckee Newton's law leaves little room for interpretations. $F=ma$ and $m$ is $mass$. 

The only approximation used here is that the water surface does not change by the motion of the cylinder. (The area of the water surface is much much larger than that of the cylinder)

Next corrections to the model should take into account viscosity, gravitational waves etc.